# winning configurations Part II --more complex polyominos -- tetris pieces

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many ways can the 2x2n (tube) board be tiled or filled with Tetris Pieces ? This is similar to other tilings except the Tetris pieces have 4 squares and have more complex configurations. The proof is a similar use of Recurrence equations then more simpler Polyominos. It has not been added to this math problem data base so thought we should add it. The reccurance is Fn^2

Comment: What math problem data base do you mean? And what answer do you have for $2 \times n$ board? Why is it a tube? are the ends joined somehow to make a donut shape? Might be good to list the Tetris shapes...

Comment: so far u are the only one to not understand my language . the term tube is used since i think of it as more of a tube then a board if its placed vertical that is and pieces fall into it lile tetris . why would u think ends are joined is a better question . and math problem data base means here ! .math stack exchange or when the name changes someday , mdbe ..math data base exchange . Lastly everyone knows what tetris pieces lool like . when u attack this problem u will end up drawing them and as a hint u will actually only end up drawing 4 ' kinds '  of the tetris shapes . good luck 

Comment: Randin-- thanks for the clarifications. I agree I could have looked up tetris pieces, and was really only confused about the tube idea, and reference to math data base which I thought was a source other than this site.

Comment: coffeemath no problem ( but this one is ..get it ? ) jokes aside this problem is interesting because the same method to solve it is , solves both the more complex polyominos beyond the tetromino ( tetris pieces ) , to the simpler ones ! i will try and attach link to the simpler case in my next comment , and as u know solving an easier case in math helps u conquer the bigger more complex cases 

Comment: It looks like you have found a proof of some kind for the number of ways to tile the $2 \times n$ board... is it a recurrence or a formula? If not too involved it would be nice to put it in the question.